# JqGrid: Sorting does not follow the right order

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

The column I am trying to sort looks like this;

[image: sort]

When you look at the image above you see that sort does not follow the right order. Jan 24
 should come before Jan 28.

Here's my client-side code :

```
$(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url:"grid_accessLog.php",
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "GET",
        colNames:["ID","Ip Address","User Info","Time","Page","Referrer","Search","User Agent","Notes"],
                colModel: [
            { name: "id",index:"id", width: 55,search:true},
            { name: "ip_address",index:"ip_address",search:true, width: 90 },
            { name: "user_info",index:"user_info",search:true, width: 100},
            { name: "time",index:"time",search:true,sorttype:"date",width: 90},
            { name: "page",index:"page",search:true, width: 120},
            { name: "referrer",index:"referrer",search:true, width: 90 },
            { name: "search",index:"search",search:true, width: 90 },
            { name: "user_agent",index:"user_agent",search:true, width: 120 },
        { name: "notes",index:"notes",search:true, width: 120 }
        ],

         pager: "#pager",
            rowNum: 30,
            rowList: [10,20,30],
            autowidth:true,
            sortname: "id",
            sortorder: "desc",
          //  loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "Access Log",
            height: 'auto'

                            }).navGrid("#pager", {search:true, edit:false,add:false,del:false,searchtext:"Search",refreshtext:"Refresh"});
                                             });//end ready
```

Here's my server-side code;

```
//Get the requested page
$page = $_GET['page'];

//Get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$limit = $_GET['rows'];

// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;

//array to translate the search type
$ops = array(
    'eq'=>'=', //equal
    'ne'=>'<>',//not equal
    'lt'=>'<', //less than
    'le'=>'<=',//less than or equal
    'gt'=>'>', //greater than
    'ge'=>'>=',//greater than or equal
    'bw'=>'LIKE', //begins with
    'bn'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't begin with
    'in'=>'LIKE', //is in
    'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', //is not in
    'ew'=>'LIKE', //ends with
    'en'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't end with
    'cn'=>'LIKE', // contains
    'nc'=>'NOT LIKE'  //doesn't contain
);
function getWhereClause($col, $oper, $val){
    global $ops;
    if($oper == 'bw' || $oper == 'bn') $val .= '%';
    if($oper == 'ew' || $oper == 'en' ) $val = '%'.$val;
    if($oper == 'cn' || $oper == 'nc' || $oper == 'in' || $oper == 'ni') $val = '%'.$val.'%';
    return " WHERE $col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";
}

$where = ""; //if there is no search request sent by jqgrid, $where should be empty
$searchField = isset($_GET['searchField']) ? $_GET['searchField'] : false;
$searchOper = isset($_GET['searchOper']) ? $_GET['searchOper']: false;
$searchString = isset($_GET['searchString']) ? $_GET['searchString'] : false;
if ($_GET['_search'] == 'true') {
    $where = getWhereClause($searchField,$searchOper,$searchString);
}

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM renal_accessLog"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count']; 

// calculate the total pages for the query 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
              $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
              $total_pages = 0; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM renal_accessLog ".$where." ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 


 $responce = new stdClass();
$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages;
$responce->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['id'],$row['ip_address'],$row['user_info'],$row['time'],$row['page'],$row['referrer'],$row['search'],$row['user_agent'],$row['notes'] );
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($responce);
```

I have the same problem on sorting an address column on another grid. I hope that if I can get this one fixed, I can apply the same logic to the other grid. Thanks for you input!

Comment: which format of data for the column `name: "time"` are in the server response from `url:"grid_accessLog.php"`?

Comment: @Oleg Man I've been hoping you would comment on one of my posts concerning JqGrid. You solutions have been of great help to me. You rock. the format is date( "M j, Y | G:i:s A" );

Comment: @Oleg I have updated the question with my server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I did was since time does not sort in the right order, and time and id are corollaries, I added this piece of checking to my query.

```
//checking if time is the sort column clicked so that we can default sidx to id..
if($sidx =='time'){
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM renal_accessLog ".$where." ORDER BY id $sord LIMIT $start, $limit";
}else{
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM renal_accessLog ".$where." ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
}
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error());
```